# Add "Show in Finder" service to Services sub-menu in OS X

Tags: macos, mac, automator

I'd like to create and add a service to the Services sub-menu under the Application menu for applications like Word, Pages etc., where the currently edited file is revealed in Finder. 
The flow I want is: open a file (myfile.doc), then go to the Application Menu, then go into Services, and I want an option there to show the file in Finder. 
How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Services from inside a text app refer to the text, not the file, so I'm not sure you'll succeed outside of a file-picker dialog.

Comment: I tried creating an automator workflow as a service, but I am only able to use the text (not the file), like you said. How can I get automator to use the current file?

Comment: It can't do it because it's not at that moment dealing with the file itself, but with the file contents. I don't think there's a 'fix' other than jimtut's workaround. [show in finder is *already* a service, btw, you just can't see it from 'inside' a document]

Answer (score 0):

How about an alternative way to do what you want, without leaving Word, etc, but without using the Services menu?

Command-click on the filename in the window's titlebar.  You should get a pop-up (or "pop-down") menu showing this file's place in your filesystem.  Move up ("down") one folder, let go, and you'll see the folder where this file resides.

I'm not on a Mac right now so can't tell you if the current file (in Word, etc.) will be highlighted in the Finder folder, but you will get to the right folder this way.

Works in almost all Mac apps, too!

Comment: I wanted to do this using automator so that I could have access to this feature and variants of it from all programs. For example I would like to be able to automatically email the currently edited file as an attachment, etc., through automator scripts.